# view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #175

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Лог ошибок

```
2020-12-21 09:09:37.049 28772-28772/com.heven.taxicabondemandtaxi.eva E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.heven.taxicabondemandtaxi.eva, PID: 28772
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #175: Binary XML file line #175: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #175: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at com.heven.taxicabondemandtaxi.eva.fragment.customer.BottomSheetFragmentBooking.onCreateView(BottomSheetFragmentBooking.java:127)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:548)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:71)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.TextAppearance.<init>(TextAppearance.java:85)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:310)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(TextInputLayout.java:1559)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:584)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at com.heven.taxicabondemandtaxi.eva.fragment.customer.BottomSheetFragmentBooking.onCreateView(BottomSheetFragmentBooking.java:127) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
```

Строка BottomSheetFragmentBooking.java:127

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_booking, container, false);
```

fragment_bottom_sheet_booking.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--<ImageView-->
        <!--android:padding="5dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/cancel"-->
        <!--app:srcCompat="@drawable/quantum_ic_clear_grey600_24"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="right"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="30dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="30dp"/>-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_cash"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:tint="@color/colorYellowDark"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_payment_cash"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="@color/colorLogoBlack"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="@string/paiement_par_cash"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="@string/m_thode_de_paiement"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/colorLogoBlack"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/choose_your_vehicle_type"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/line_divider_driver"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
            android:background="@color/colorLogoBlack"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:background="@drawable/custom_cash"
                android:padding="1.5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/trajet_ride"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorLogoBlack"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar_ride"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|left">

                <ImageView
                    android:tint="@color/colorYellowDark"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_distance"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="@string/distance"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|left">

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/distance_requete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/intput_layout_place"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                <EditText
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorLogoBlack"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_location_pin_"
                    android:hint="@string/specify_exactly_your_location"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/input_place"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/intput_layout_people_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                <EditText
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorLogoBlack"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_team"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:hint="@string/number_of_people"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/people_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorLogoBlack"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|left">

                <ImageView
                    android:tint="@color/colorYellowDark"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time_outline"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="@string/dur_e"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|left">

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/duree_requete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|left">

                <ImageView
                    android:tint="@color/colorYellowDark"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_money"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="@string/co_t"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|left">

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/cout_requete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/add_favorite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:text="@string/add_to_favorite"
                android:textColor="@color/colorLogoBlack"/>

            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_second"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Это 175 строка

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Вот полный код

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/intput_layout_place"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                <EditText
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorLogoBlack"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_location_pin_"
                    android:hint="@string/specify_exactly_your_location"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/input_place"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Стили TextLabel

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#70757A</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>-->
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorLogoBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorLogoBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorLogoBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorLogoBlack</item>
    <item name="colorAccent" tools:ignore="DuplicateDefinition">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Судя по логам `UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute` - у вас в разметке какая-то кастомная вьюха, и в ней проблема с атрибутами внутри какая-то

Comment: Покажите свою разметку (xml файл)

Comment: @Barmaley Разметку скинул

Comment: Покажите 175-ую строку в вашей разметке.

Comment: Судя по всему проблема здесь: `android:theme="@style/TextLabel"` - посмотрите синтаксис стиля `TextLabel`